# Why does my object tilt when I go from edit mode to object mode?

Tags: modeling, objects, edit-mode, object-mode

I'm completely new to Blender and was trying to follow some Youtube tutorial. I was working with an object in Edit mode and when I go back to Object mode it rotated a bit. What might have caused this and how can I fix this? [image: As you can see in the image below, the left screenshots are what displayed in Edit mode and the ones on the right is in Object mode.]

Comment: We can see in the outliner that your object have a modifier. Which could be deforming your object. Could you show us that modifier ?